# Random data display to TextView in android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

**Any help me? I want to display random data  from SQliteDB to multi TextView, thanks!**

```
 protected void setQuestionView(){
    txta.setText(currentQ.getOptOne());
    txtb.setText(currentQ.getOptTwo());
    txtc.setText(currentQ.getOptThree());
    txtd.setText(currentQ.getOptFour());
```

Comment: Please show us the code that you've tried with and the difficulty you are having with it.

Comment: I want to show random data to four TextView, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you've extracted the data as a cursor, you could get the number of rows using `int randomrange = (cursor.getCount()) -1;` *(obviously if range is less than 0 then there are no rows)*.

Once you have obtained the random number as an integer, then you can use `cursor.moveToPosition(randomposition)` to move the cursor. You can then do `txta.setText(cursor.getString(columnoffset));` or if you wish to use the column's name then you could use `txta.settext(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(columnasstring)));`

You could then repeat this 4 times. However, you have a chance to have the same text values.

An alternative way is to have the cursor extract the required number of random rows e.g. base the query on the following SQL :-

`SELECT * FROM yourtable ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 4;`